# Magento 2 Close (Esc) button translate

Tags: magento-2.1, javascript, html, inline-translations

How i can translate "Close (Esc)" button? I tried add translate csv file "Close (Esc)","text (Esc)" but doesn't work.

This is below code what need edit?

Javascript

```
'class': 'action primary',
click: function () {
this.closeModal();
$('.mfp-close', parentBody).trigger('click');
```

Html

```
<button title="Close (Esc)" type="button" class="mfp-close">×</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use your JS to transform the string translatable and then apply using JS in the HTML, so you can change in your CSV file.

```
$.mage.__('<string>');
```

**Further information**

To ensure that the text you add in .html templates of UI components is added to the dictionary, mark the text using the i18n custom binding. The following code samples illustrate how it should be used for different cases of adding a text:

when a string is added in the scope of an HTML element:

```
<span data-bind="i18n: 'Sign In'"></span>
```

when a string is added with no binding to an HTML element:

```
<!-- ko i18n: 'You have no items in your shopping cart.' --><!-- /ko -->
```

[Reference on DevDocs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/translations/translate_theory.html)

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work? $.mage.__('.mfp-close', parentBody).trigger('click');